# number of cores in the ARM Cortex A9

Tags: arm, cortex-a, zynq

I'm using Zedboard with Zynq Chip. I want to know the number of cores per CPU (in the board there is two, CPU0 and CPU1, but there is no indication of the number of cores!). Thanks.

Comment: Er, "core" is short for "CPU core", as in a functional, self-contained CPU (but not necessarily caches and timers and other stuff which can be shared)...

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but in the Zedboard is indicated that the Zynq chip has two CPU Cortex A-9 (with cache L1) MPcore, that means multicores per CPU ??? it is a confusion for me. So i want to know, the zynq contains two CPU (with 4 cores for each cpu) or two cores called CPU0 and CPU1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first check Zynq's [documentation](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds190-Zynq-7000-Overview.pdf). Then one should proceed to search what is inside a [ARM Cortex-A9](http://www.arm.com/cortex-a9.php). With both in mind you should be able to notice that what you have is two cores (CPU0 and CPU1). You are probably confusing your device with modern processors that have multiple cores. Look for in Google: "What is a core/CPU".
I hope that this answer gives you the pointers to better understand what a core is and what your device's cores provide.